# Downloading entire web pages within domain

Tags: windows, download, website, wget

My computer in on LAN. I'm connected to the local domain at MyDomain. Within that domain exists something like WIKI for a training (`http://training-wiki/`). I would like to download entire WIKI into my PC to make it available for chosen clients. I found something called HTTrack but it doesn't seem to work. Our domain needs a login and password. Is there any tool that handles such a case?

I tried some other programs, but the same problem. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I get:

> 401 Unauthorized

I tried wget:

```
wget --http-user=MyDomain\UserName --http-passwd=MyPassword --mirror -p --html-extension --convert-links http://training-wiki/
```

but getting the same `401 Unauthorized`.

**[EDIT]**

It's not a duplicate. I said I want to download entire web site within domain using login/password. Programs listed in "duplicated" thread don't solve my problem at all... Please, READ the question before you mark it as a duplicated one...

Comment: Include `--server-response` would give you more detail as to what is going on here.

Comment: It gives `Unknown authentication scheme. Authorization failed.`

Comment: Could you post the full output log. Things like wget version might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm)'s HTML Spider feature might be what you're looking for. It even supports user login and password.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it seems like this program downloads only one subpage. Can't work recursively and can't remake URLs inside to work well on local\